# Count the number of variables containing objects

Tags: powershell

I have an issue with .count. Its to do with the way it counts objects and also arrays containing objects.

For dull reasons, I have a situation where I don't know if what is being passed into my function is a single array of objects or 2 or more variables holding array lists of objects.

I though it would be easy to detect this. But because of the way count tries to help me out I am having trouble. When 2 or more arrays of objects are returned count reflects the number of arrays. But when only one is return count reflects the amount of objects in that array.

Simplified demo using simple arrays:

```
$Arr1 = "a","b","c"
$Arr2 ="d","f","e"

$arrayjoined = $Arr1,$Arr2

#count showing the number of arrays = 2
$arrayjoined.count

# Count on just one array = 3
$Arr1.count
```

My original function works apart from occasions when only one array is returned. Is there any thing I can do to check for this, or force the count to return 1 to reflect just one array returned?

PS. I know I can use += to get the results into the same array in the example above but I can't do this with the arrays coming into my function.

Comment: "apart from some occasions when only one array is returned." - please show us code that actually _reproduces this behavior_ (rather than the code you _don't_ have problems with)

Comment: i do have issues with the above code. it demos the issue i have. i don't understand your point. i already states that i can't control if multiple arrays are returned or not.

Comment: I guess I'm confused by the sentence "So everything works in my function" immediately after the sample code...

Comment: have reworded for clarity

Answer (score 1):

So what can we do if we can to count arrays in a array

```
$Array = 1,2,3
$CountArray = $Array
$CountArray.Length
$CountArray.Count
```

Will return

```
3
3
```

We can instead prepend the array with a `,`

```
$Array = 1,2,3
$CountArray = ,$Array
$CountArray.Length
$CountArray.Count
```

Which will return

```
1
1
```

You can also add to an array like this

```
$Array = @()
$Array += ,@(1,2,3)
$Array.Length
$Array.Count
```

Returns

```
1
1
```